# GridDB: Error Code 9201 - Authentication failure when connecting to the database

Tags: database-connection, griddb

I am attempting to connect to a GridDB database, but I am receiving an authentication failure error with code 9201. The error message states: "Failed to connect to the database due to authentication failure." I have already confirmed that the provided login credentials, such as the username and password, are correct. What could be the cause of this issue?

**What I Tried:**

I have double-checked the accuracy of the username and password for the GridDB database connection, but I am still receiving the authentication failure error (Error code 9201).

**Expected Outcome:**

I expect to be able to successfully connect to the GridDB database using the provided credentials, without encountering any authentication failure errors.

Comment: Please provide more information: how did you install GridDB? are you using default credential or have you created a new one? and where are you trying to connect from?